# Django type object 'Account' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD' django

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

i tried to adding username=None didnt work
Account model is for auth

other models that are diffrent languge are just profile pic or date joined nothing important to the error  i imagine

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):     
    email= models.EmailField(verbose_name='ایمیل', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    مسکن = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    تاریخ_ثبت_نام = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='تاریخ_ثبت_نام', auto_now_add=True)
    اخرین_ورود = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='اخرین_ورود', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    عکس_پروفایل = models.ImageField(max_length=255 ,upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath,null=True ,blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
    objects = MyAccountManager()
    
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

def get_profile_image_filenames(self):
    return str(self.عکس_پروفایل)[str(self.عکس_پروفایل).index(f'uploads/{self.pk})/'):]

def has_perm(self,perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin
def has_module_perm(self , applabel):
    return True
```

Comment: You should indent it properly, such that `USERNAME_FIELD` and `REQUIRED_FIELDS` (with `S`) are members of the `Account` model.

Comment: can i ask how i mean you mean i should change their postion but where